# Laravel MethodNotAllowedHttpException error en ruta Resource

Tags: laravel

Tengo una pregunta, al momento de intentar actualizar un dato me salta el error de MethodNotAllowedHttpException, tengo entendido que este error sale cuando existe un problema con las rutas que son `get` y deberían ser `post` pero en mi caso mi ruta es `resource`:

web.php

```
Route::resource('inventario', 'InventarioController');
```

Controlador (funcion update)

```
   public function update(Request $request, $id)
   {
       $this->validate($request,[ 'cantidad'=>'required']);
       Inventario::find($id)->update($request->all());
       return redirect()->route('inventario.show')->with('success','Registro actualizado satisfactoriamente');
   }
```

Vista (show.blade.php)

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('inventario.update', $inv->id_inventario )}}" role="form">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
     <div class="form row">
         <input type="hidden" name="id_inventario" class="form-control input-sm" id="id_inventario"
                                   value="{{ $inv->id_inventario }}">
         <input type="number" name="cantidad" class="form-control input-sm" id="cantidad"
                                   value="{{ $inv->cantidad }}">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-success">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>

     </div>
 </form>
```

En mi caso al momento de dar clic a el botón de actualizar se abre un modal, que es donde me aparecen los datos que quiero actualizar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu vista, tu formulario, debería contener lo siguiente para indicar que es una acción de actualización

```
@method('PUT')
```

Dicho verbo `PUT` servirá para indicar que es una acción de actualización; esto va en tu formulario; desde que en los formularios; los únicos métodos que se pueden especificar son `POST` y `GET`

Ahora deberías declarar por separado dicha ruta, para poder distinguir una acción de la otra

```
Route::put('/inventario', 'InventarioController@update');
```

La ruta anterior, debería ir justo antes de la declaración de tu `ResourceController`; como puedes notar al final con el operador `@` indico el nombre del método al que deseo acceder que en este caso el el de `update`